# SQL Server 2008 - Getting specific rows like 200-300

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server table called `pluginProspects` and I have the following columns..

```
FirstName
LastName
Email
AmonutOfEmployees
AnnualRevenue
```

In this table I have thousand of rows, and I wanted to create a SQL statement that allows me to retrieve rows 200 - 300 or even rows 300 - 400 or w/e I want.

I use to use this following code which worked for a while, BUT I want to add specific `WHERE` clause and its not showing me hundred results, its showing me like 50 or 70 or w/e depending on the results from those specific row numbers

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
   (SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY demoID DESC) AS rownum, 
        demoID, RecordStatus, Email, FirstName, LastName, AmountOfEmployees, 
        AnnualRevenue 
    FROM 
        pluginProspects) AS Salaries1 
WHERE 
    rownum BETWEEN 1 * {STARTNUMBERHERE} - 100 AND 1 * {STARTNUMBERHERE} 
    AND (RecordStatus = '2014 Lead') 
    AND (AmonutofEmployees > 10) 
ORDER BY 
    AmountOfEmployees DESC
```

As you can see `{STARTNUMBERHERE}` I could put 100, 200, 300, 400 etc to create a paging effect which worked perfectly fine UNTIL I added `(AmountofEmployees > 10)`

Well in my table there tons of prospects that have less than 10 employees, so this will sometimes only show 10 or 20 results, instead of the first 100 results.

Anyone know the correct way I should be doing this? No I can't use a stored procedure for what I'm trying to do, it has to be pure SQL based

Comment: Move the where clausole (except rownum pagination) inside the subquery

Comment: Max can you modify and show me what you mean? Yea sorry its not in a good displayable format I just copied it out of my code which just stores it inside a single line textbox

Comment: He's saying move the where clause (recordstatus and pluginprospects) inside the subquery. So `FROM pluginProspects WHERE RecordStatus = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matt,

Max meant to change it to look like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
   (SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY demoID DESC) AS rownum, 
        demoID, RecordStatus, Email, FirstName, LastName, AmountOfEmployees, 
        AnnualRevenue 
    FROM 
        pluginProspects
    WHERE   (RecordStatus = '2014 Lead') 
            AND (AmonutofEmployees > 10) ) AS Salaries1 
WHERE 
    rownum BETWEEN 1 * {STARTNUMBERHERE} - 100 AND 1 * {STARTNUMBERHERE}  
ORDER BY 
    AmountOfEmployees DESC
```